# Change font dynamically of textview in fragment

Tags: android, fonts, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I have a class that extends FragmentActivity, inside Fragment that I've created there's only a textView.

I'd like to put a setting button on actionbar (already done) that could make user change font type of this textView.

How could I achive this?

I've another problem, that number of Fragment in FragmentActivity is not known a priori...
So when I change my font type I'd like to change on every Fragment.

I've tried to put a method changefont inside my Fragment, but I have no idea how I could manage..

```
public void setFont(){
            TextView textView = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.detailsText);
            textView.setTypeface();
//Another problem how set typeface, because
//Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/font.tff"); couldn't work because I'm inside a Fragment and getAssets() just rise errors..
        }
```

I'm quite stuck.. Could you guys help me?

Answer (score 0):

Make one class something called Utils.java and put this method:-

```
public static void setFontSignika_Bold(TextView textView) {
            Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(textView.getContext()
                    .getAssets(), "fonts/signikabold.ttf");

            textView.setTypeface(tf);

        }
```

Now, you can use this in whole application by this way:-

```
Utils.setFontSignika_Bold(textView); // Pass your textview object
```

Comment: I got a NullPointerExeption, because I'm trying to access to a TextView inside  a Fragment from ActionBar. So when I call this method I'm using as parameter ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.text)); but of course this will rise an exception

Answer (score 0):

You can also create subclass of TextView and set font inside. Context object contains getAssets() method :)

Example implementation of extended text view:

```
public class TextViewPlus extends TextView {
  private static final String TAG = "TextView";

  public TextViewPlus(Context context) {
      super(context);
  }

  public TextViewPlus(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
      super(context, attrs);
      setCustomFont(context, attrs);
  }

  public TextViewPlus(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
      super(context, attrs, defStyle);
      setCustomFont(context, attrs);
  }

  private void setCustomFont(Context ctx, AttributeSet attrs) {
      TypedArray a = ctx.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.TextViewPlus);
      String customFont = a.getString(R.styleable.TextViewPlus_customFont);
      setCustomFont(ctx, customFont);
      a.recycle();
  }

  public boolean setCustomFont(Context ctx, String asset) {
      Typeface tf = null;
      try {
        tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(ctx.getAssets(), asset);
      } catch (Exception e) {
          Log.e(TAG, "Could not get typeface: "+e.getMessage());
          return false;
      }

      setTypeface(tf);
    setPaintFlags(getPaintFlags() | Paint.SUBPIXEL_TEXT_FLAG | Paint.DEV_KERN_TEXT_FLAG);
      return true;
  }

}
```

Comment: Not my first problem, I have to access to a TextView inside a Fragment from ActionBar :/